# Get position of each row based on ORDER

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

I have a highscore table that has three columns, name, highScore, rep. Currently I loop through the results ORDERED by rep. I have an $i est within the loop and this displays as rank eg:

```
SELECT highScore, name, rep FROM  table1 ORDER BY rep DESC

while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) 
        {
                echo "<tr>";
                echo "<td>" . $i . "</td>"; // rank
                echo "<td>" . $row["name"] . "</td>"; // name
                echo "<td>" . $row["rep"] . "</td>"; // rep
                echo "<td>" . $row["highScore"] . "</td>"; // high score
                echo "</tr>";
                $i++;
            }
        }
```

Currently this works without fault. The problem is that i have now implemened a "sort by" button which changes the SQL to ORDER to `highScore` instead of `rep`. the only problem is that the Rank does not match now. Is there a way of getting and echoing the position of each row based on `rep` and then seslcting and ordering based on `highScore`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select * from 
(
  SELECT highScore, name, rep, @rank := @rank + 1 as rank 
  FROM table1, (select @rank := 0) r
  ORDER BY rep DESC
) alias_name
order by highscore desc
```

`rank` contains your rank by `rep` and the table is ordered by `highscore` now.

Comment: Thanks, I'm in the process of trying it but seem to be getting an error. I'm confused by the `alias_name` bit?

Comment: You need to give every subquery an alias name.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this,

```
       SELECT highScore, name, rep,pos FROM 
        (
        SELECT t.name, @rownum := @rownum + 1 AS pos
        FROM `table1` t, (SELECT @rownum := 0) r
        ORDER BY t.rep DESC) `table1` 

    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) 
    {
            echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td>" . $i . "</td>"; // rank
            echo "<td>" . $row["name"] . "</td>"; // name
            echo "<td>" . $row["rep"] . "</td>"; // rep
            echo "<td>" . $row["highScore"] . "</td>"; // high score
            echo "<td>" . $row["pos"] . "</td>"; // position
            echo "</tr>";
            $i++;
        }
```